# How to make an event on one element cause a bootstrap popover on another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Am trying to create a picture upload button with js, that will have the following functionality....

1)Pop up file chooser on click (accomplished)

2)Preview image selected inside a bootstrap popover when the image is selected from file chooser...

The button contains an input tag of type file, with a css class(.file-inputs) that applies a display of none on the element, so I cant add the popover to the input tag since popovers don't work on hidden elements, how can I make the popover display on the visible button when the value of the input tag is changed

Maybe something like so

```js
$('#photo').change()(function(){
  
if(!($("#photo").val() == '')){
  
  //Use bootstrap popover to show image over button
  
      
    });
  
  });
```

Here is the button code

```html
<button class="btn btn-default" rel="popover" id="btn-photo">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i>
  <input class="file-inputs" type="file" name="photo" id="photo" />
</button>
```

And here is the js

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var img = '';

  //Event to display file chooser
  $('.post-box').on('click', '#btn-photo', function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var elem = document.getElementById('photo');
    if (elem && document.createEvent) {
      var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
      // Event(event_type:String, bubbles:Boolean, cancelable:Boolean)
      evt.initEvent("click", false, true);
      elem.dispatchEvent(evt);


    }


  });

  // Show popover on button

  $("#btn-photo").popover({
    placement: 'top',
    trigger: 'click',
    title: 'Add a picture to your post! :)',
    content: img,
    html: true
  });
  // });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

A fast answer is something like this:

```
$("#yourbutton").on("yourevent", function(){$("#otherbutton").trigger("click");});
```

Comment: thanks @Enrico, but the first one #yourbutton is supposed to be #file with a change event, the file input tag is buried inside #ortherbutton so using this method will get the file chooser poped up again, but I will try to use the idea in some other way... thanks

Comment: Well, for your specific case you probably want to create your own popover, since I'm not that sure you can place images inside bootstrap popover.
If this is the case i could help you do it

Comment: Eventhough images can be added into bootstrap popovers, I would love your help with a custom popover, thanks

Comment: Why not place the popover on the button?